# change in end point path in application.yml resulting in "Full authentication is required to access this resource" spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Postman to proxy call an endpoint of an application. Earlier the path in the application.yml file was like "/abc/**". Now I had prefixed to something like "/xyz/abc/**". With zuul configuration I am proxy calling this endpoint where I am facing following error in Postman.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1531456942044,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/xyz/abc/admin"
}
```

Prefixing endpoint is what the only change I have made.

Below is the zuul configuration in application.yml file

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    orders:
      stripPrefix: false
      path: /xyz/abc/**
      url: ${APPLICATION_URL:http://localhost:8009}
```

Comment: can you post the changed code? @user

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: have you tried by reverting this changes backs? just to find is this because of this change? @swetha

Comment: yes, I did. Reverting the change is working fine.

Comment: i think you should try this `If sensitiveHeaders is set on a route, it overrides the global sensitiveHeaders setting.` @swetha https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Comment: still, it is not working. same issue